# What do the ellipses mean in $x^TW_{\dots ij}$

Tags: matrices, notation

I cam across this notation: $x^TW_{\dots ij}$. I don't understand the notation. Why are there 3 dots?

Source: http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/proceedings/papers/v28/goodfellow13.pdf, top of second page, second column.

Comment: Can you provide more details? In what context did you see this notations? Which note/course are you following?

Comment: http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/proceedings/papers/v28/goodfellow13.pdf top of second page, second column.

Comment: I would guess (from the context) $x^T W_{\cdots ij} =\sum_{\alpha = 1}^d x_\alpha W_{\alpha ij}$.